# AngularJS: ng-keypress is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui

Problem: ng-keypress is not working but if I replace `ng-keypress` with `ng-click` then `filterSearchData($event)` function is working.

**HTML:-**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Custom Plunker</title>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ng-grid.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ng-grid.debug.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
            <input type="text" ng-keypress="filterSearchData($event)" />
            <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
        </body>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JS:**-

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.filterSearchData = function(element) {
        console.log(element);
    };
});
```

Comment: What version of Angular are you using? I don't believe it's always been supported

Comment: @lan: I am using AngularJS v1.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I recommend to use [`ng-change`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) instead of `ng-keypress`.

```
// HTML:
<input type="text" ng-model="filter" ng-change="filterSearchData()" />

// Controller:
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.filterSearchData = function() {
        console.log($scope.filter);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason you have to use such an old version of angular, which doesn't support `ngKeypress` directive, you can always add your own implementation. It's pretty easy to do, for example `onKeypress` directive:

```
app.directive('onKeypress', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            handler: '&onKeypress'
        },
        link: function(scope, element) {
            element.bind('keypress', function(e) {
                scope.handler({$event: e});
            });
        }
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" on-keypress="filterSearchData($event)" />
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/OorXMYKZeXI9Lrc1wrRY?p=preview